Extract table from HTML webpage by using Python and transform it into Latex language
Is there an easy way to get python to extract a table from HTML and transform it into readable Latex syntax?
I have a table on an HTML webpage, which i would like python to automatically convert into Latex syntax, is this possible? I am Using Python 3.12 through Anaconda. And the webpage is(just for testing):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics
And since there are many tables, how would one control which table is exported?
I have tried with this:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Step 1: Get the HTML content from the webpage
url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics"
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()  # Ensure we notice bad responses

# Step 2: Parse the HTML to find the table
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')

# Function to convert HTML table to LaTeX
def html_table_to_latex(table):
    latex_code = "\\begin{tabular}{|" + " | ".join("l" * len(table.find_all('th'))) + "|}\n"
    latex_code += "\\hline\n"

    # Step 3: Extract table headers
    headers = table.find_all('th')
    header_row = " & ".join(th.text.strip() for th in headers) + " \\\\"
    latex_code += header_row + "\n"
    latex_code += "\\hline\n"

    # Step 4: Extract table rows
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all(['td', 'th'])
        if cols:
            latex_row = " & ".join(td.text.strip() for td in cols) + " \\\\"
            latex_code += latex_row + "\n"
            latex_code += "\\hline\n"

    latex_code += "\\end{tabular}"

    return latex_code

# Convert the HTML table to LaTeX
latex_table = html_table_to_latex(table)

# Output the LaTeX table
print(latex_table) 

With this outcome:
\begin{tabular}{|l | l|}
\hline
Prerequisites: & Objective: \\
\hline
Prerequisites: & The basics of HTML (see
        Introduction to HTML). \\
\hline
Objective: & To gain basic familiarity with HTML tables. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

And this in Latex:
enter image description here
but the table should look like this:
enter image description here

table = soup.find('table') will try to find the first  element. Use soup.find_all('table') to discover all tables
